# alt-tab completion while using SSH

Tags: 11.10, ssh, console, auto-completion

I just recently discovered that pressing alt-tab on a console window allows me to autocomplete from the last commands and parameters I used.
Very useful!

But when using SSH from Windows this feature is obviusly lost.

Is there a way to remap this function to another key(s)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the action tied to readline's function `dynamic-complete-history`.

You can redefine such action in `~/.inputrc`, for example to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> with

```
$include /etc/inputrc
"\ez": dynamic-complete-history
```

where `\e` means <kbd>ESC</kbd> and is equivalent to an <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier.

Also take into account this other possible solution: [How to quickly store and access often used commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26245/how-to-quickly-store-and-access-often-used-commands/26246#26246)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Indeed, history-search-backward and history-search-forward are very useful. Especially when I forget to press Ctrl-R before entering the partial command.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is a hot key in Windows and in several unix window managers. In these environments, this key combination does not filter down to applictions.

In a text terminal, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+key is usually translated to `ESC` followed by the corresponding key. (This can be overridden in some terminals' configuration, but usually isn't.) So you can type <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to invoke this command.